# Mapping multipule textures to one object in blender

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I am using blender to create game assets that I will later export to unity. For the project I am working on I wish to model a factory floor. The floor it's self will consist of two maybe three different textures. Is it best to UV map these textures separately and bake a new texture in blender? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you want to make the most out of your textures, you should work out a way that you can reuse them as much as possible. By baking them into one texture, you reduce that ability.

Comment: I'd be inclined to prepare the multiple textures in a graphics editor first.  Gimp is one that comes to mind.  Once happy with the result, use that as a single texture (image) in Blender.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use this in a mobile game, then it's best to place all the floor images onto a single texture.  UV unwrap the floor onto a single image and only have one texture (with the 3 different floor images on the single texture).

This way the game engine will only need to bind and sample a single texure (instead of 3) just to draw a simple floor.  I'm thinking of optimisation here, and if you can fit the 3 images onto a single texture, then that is the best way to go.